# Mermaid class diagrams get wider only, ignore direction

Tags: gitlab, mermaid

I am having a problem using Mermaid syntax to layout class diagrams inside GitLab markdown. I have some evidence that I made a mistake in my Mermaid syntax, irrespective of GitLab. Thus, I felt it OK to ask on *SO*.

The class diagrams I am trying to create with Mermaid only lays out wider and wider as I add elements. The text in the diagram also get smaller and smaller. I cannot get the layout to expand vertically instead.

Here is screen shot with H1 element for reference.

[image: mermaid class diagram]

I added the `direction` key word, but the layout ignores it. I have tried `TD` and `TB` and `LR` and `RL` for `direction` values. The class diagrams renders the same in all cases.

I found this [a more complicated diagram](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/37282) that renders nicely in GitLab. That layout uses both horizontal and vertical space. This makes me think that GitLab is working, but my syntax is wrong.

How do I get Mermaid to expand more vertically instead of horizontally and/or to not reduce the text size so much?

Here is the code:

```
classDiagram
%% Direction does not seem to be working?
direction TB
%% ---- Lib Classes ----
class Lib_FancyFruit
class Lib_GoodBread{
    +Double yeastAmount
}
Lib_FancyFruit *-- "0..*" Lib_GoodBread : breads
class Lib_SeasideManor
class Lib_LiberalSpice{
    +String currentFlavor
}
Lib_SeasideManor *-- "0..*" Lib_LiberalSpice : spicesAllAround
class Lib_PrimeCurrents
class Lib_GardenFresh
Lib_GardenFresh *-- "0..*" Lib_PrimeCurrents : currentCurrents
class Lib_RepeatingHistory
class Lib_TranslationInformation
class Lib_HistoryLayerAgain
Lib_RepeatingHistory *-- "0..*" Lib_TranslationInformation : recentHistory
Lib_TranslationInformation *-- "0..*" Lib_HistoryLayerAgain : anotherTranslationInformation
%% ---- Interfaces ----
class HappinessSadnessDisplay{
    <<interface>>
    ~String formattedCurrentThings
    ~Date onceDate
    ~String formattedDayDate
    ~String goryDetail
    ~String firstName
    ~Bool workComplete
    ~Bool appointmentScheduled
}
class RedTrainSchedule{
    <<interface>>
    ~Double dailyCrayonsDue
    ~Bool willBeOnTimeToday
    ~createFreightTrainRailLine() FreightTrainRailLine
}
%% ---- Enums ----
class Pill{
    <<enumeration>>
    reallyOval
    circularizedKind
}
%% ---- Main Classes ----
class WanderingMan
WanderingMan o-- "1" Lib_LiberalSpice : spice
WanderingMan o-- "0..1" Pill : pill
WanderingMan o-- "0..1" Lib_GardenFresh : gardenAccounts
WanderingMan o-- "0..1" PoliteHamAction : hamStory
WanderingMan o-- "0..1" PoliteHamAction : scheduledPorkchops
WanderingMan o-- "0..1" Lib_GoodBread : unwrappedBread
WanderingMan ..|> RedTrainSchedule
WanderingMan ..|> HappinessSadnessDisplay
class PoliteHamAction{
    ~String porkNumber
}
PoliteHamAction o-- "1" Lib_HistoryLayerAgain : actionLayerDetail
```

Comment: Same issue here, any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @PiotrL I never solved it. I lived with wide diagrams. However, my GitLab installation has been upgraded since I originally wrote this question, and now some of my diagrams that were too wide render taller instead. So there has been some improvement.